# How to pull same row from another table by date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table .

```
first table 

    f_id | date    |
    --------------
    1    |2012-1-01
    1    |2012-1-02

    second table 

    s_id | f_id | name
    -------------------
    1    | 1    |rakib 
    2    | 1    | shohug
```

i want to view this data 
like

```
f_id| date     | s_id | name
--------------------------
1   |2012-1-01 | 1    | rakib 
1   |2012-1-01 | 2    | shohug
1   |2012-1-02 | 1    | rakib 
1   |2012-1-02 | 2    | shohug
```

plz help me how to write it in mysql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just mean

```
SELECT first.f_id, first.date, second.s_id, second.name
  FROM first JOIN second ON second.f_id = first.f_id
```

?

(See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).)

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.f_id, f.`date`, s.s_id, s.`name`
from firsttable f
join secondtable s on f.f_id=s.f_id
order by f.f_id, f.`date`, s.s_id
```

Comment: it pull two rows from same f_id by difference date sow its pull 4 rows for two date

Comment: @rakibulalam do u have duplicate data in ur tables?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to do `FULL OUTER` join  it includes all rows from both tables. Mysql does't support it directly.

But you can try below:

```
select * from firsttable  as a
   left outer join secondtable as o on a.f_id = o.f_id
union all
select * from firsttable as a
   right outer join secondtable as o on a.f_id = o.f_id
```

Also go through this article will help you http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/